# Prove that $\{\sin x,\cos x\}$ is linearly independent in the vector space $F[0, 2\pi]$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$F[0, 2\pi]$ is a vector space of functions defined in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$.

In my opinion, all we want to do is to prove all $s$ and $t$ that satisfy $t\sin x+s\cos x = 0$ are $0$. However, it's not correct because we can easily solve this equation and we'll see that as long as $x$ is in a certain relation with $s$ and $t$, the equation works.

Can anyone help me here please?

Comment: x isn't a bound variable. So you're not finding a solution, you're finding an everywhere-zero function

Comment: Test your equation with $x=0$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ then you will have $s=t=0$

Comment: Agreeing with Jason. Sure that relation could work for *some* $x$, but you won't satisfy it universally, for *all* $x$ unless both $s,t$ are zero.

Comment: Then how should I prove that for all x, s and t must be zero?

Comment: @RaziehNoori Sorry I didn't quite get what you mean. Why would testing these values for x show that s and t must be zero for all x? Would you mind explaining more please?

Comment: see you have  $t\sin x+s\cos x = 0$ for all $x\in[0, 2\pi]$ specialy for $x=0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @RaziehNoori and these two special cases would make s=t=0 for all x in this interval because......?

Comment: you are going to show that this two function are linearly independent, 0k? thus you have written $t\cos x+s\sin x=0$, you want to show $s=t=0$ nothing more

Comment: You are to show that there are no $s,t$ such that [for all $x$, $s\sin x + t\cos x = 0$], unless $s=t=0$. If $s$ and $t$ are such that for all $x$, $s\sin x + t\cos x = 0$, then in particular, this identity holds for $x=0$ and for $x = \pi/2$. What can you conclude about $s,t$?

Comment: @RaziehNoori ah right! The vector is now the functions, and x is just arbitrary values in that interval. So it's really just about the functions but the specific values. Thank you very much.

Comment: @BrianO got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Yep, the vectors *are* functions. Glad you got it, & you're welcome.